# Как настроить nginx на раздачу 2ух разных папок со статикой по разным url?

Tags: nginx

Всем привет!

Есть 2 папки с сайтами **/site1** и **/site2**

-Если мы **на домашней** странице **site.com/**, nginx должен отдавать index.html и всю статику с папки **/site1**

-Если мы **не на домашней** (например **site.com/some**), то nginx должен отдавать index.html и статику с папки **/site2**

Пытался сделать через связку root и "location = /" с "location /", но при таком конфиге всегда отдаётся **/site2** :

```
server {
  server_name site.com;

  location = / {
    root /home/site1;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  location / {
    root /home/site2;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

Кажется это как-то связано с тем, что из-за директивы **"index index.html"**, мы никогда не попадаем на чистый "location = /". Но в таком случае тоже не понятно как поступить

Заранее спасибо

--- UPD

Уточнение, например, если у меня такая структура файлов:

```
/site1
    index.html
    main.js
    main.css

/site2
    index.html
    othername.js
    main.css
```

То когда пользователь заходит на **site.ru/** ему должен отдаваться сайт с папки **site1/** (это gatsby сайт)

А если любой другой урл, например **site.ru/abc**, то должен отдаваться уже сайт с паки **site2/** (это react сайт)

Comment: тоесть из папки `site1` всегда будет выдаваться только `index.html` ,  a c `site2`  - все остальное?

Comment: Не совсем, это 2 независимых сайта, их index'ы лежат внутри  (дополнил вопрос структурой)

Answer (score 0):

Автор я не уверен, что правильно тебя понял. В качестве костыля можно сначала чекнуть есть ли запрашиваемый файл в `site1`, если нет то ищем в `site2`

```
server {
  server_name site.com;

  location @site2 {
    root /home/site2;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

  location / {
    root /home/site1;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri /index.html @site2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Привет, дополнил свой вопрос с примером структуры файлов. В комментариях нету форматирования